# no proper 'z' matrix specified in contour()

Tags: r, contour

I am trying to do a simple contour plot in R, but I am getting the following error that `"no proper 'z' matrix specified"`.
Following is my code:

```
r=read.table("test.dat")
dim(r)
## [1] 56  3

x=matrix(unlist(r[,3]),ncol=112,byrow=T)
dim(x)
## [1] 1 11

image((1:nrow(x))-56,(1:ncol(x))-56,x)
contour((1:nrow(x))-56,(1:ncol(x))-56,x , add=TRUE)

## Error in contour.default((1:nrow(x)) - 56,
##   (1:ncol(x)) - 56, x, add = TRUE) :
##     no proper 'z' matrix specified
```

Could someone help me where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The code of `contour.default` (which you can print by typing the name of the function at the prompt in the R console) contains the line:

```
 if (!is.matrix(z) || 
     nrow(z) <= 1L || 
     ncol(z) <= 1L) 
     stop("no proper 'z' matrix specified")
```

... in other words, `contour()` refuses to try to handle a matrix that has only a single row or only a single column.  Is that really what you intended to plot? If so, perhaps you can explain the context slightly more fully?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes x (z slices) is a single column and I want to plot them. I am sorry for explaining properly and editing the question.